# REST-ful way to design hierarchical configuration resource?

Tags: rest

I am designing a DCC (dynamic currency conversion) service, and this service needs to have a configuration for each service owner (user).

The service owners have a hierarchy: MerchantGroup -> Merchant -> Site.

The expected behaviour is that, if we don't have configuration on "site" level, we use the configuration on "merchant" level. Same for "merchant" and "merchant group". If none exist, return 404.

I have the following API

PATCH /api/v1/dcc-config/:ownerType/:ownerId - patch the configuration for a given service user

Request Body:

```json
{
    "dccProvider1":{
        "isEnabled": true,
        "properties": {
            // provider specific props
        }
    },
    "dccProvider2":{
        "isEnabled": true,
        "properties": {
            // provider specific props
        }
    }
}
```

GET /api/v1/dcc-config/:ownerType/:ownerId

Response Body:

```json
{
    "isInherited": true,
    "inheritedFrom": {
        "ownerType": "Merchant",
        "ownerId": "abc"
    }
    "dccProvider1":{
        "isEnabled": true,
        "properties": {
            // provider specific props
        }
    },
    "dccProvider2":{
        "isEnabled": true,
        "properties": {
            // provider specific props
        }
    }
}
```

My questions are:

Is this restful? I am conflicted, because a change in the "merchant/123" resource can have an effect on the "site/123" resource.

If it is not how to make it restful?

Is it mandatory to return 404, or am I allowed to return an empty object if no configurations exist for the hierarchy?